# Since then with past simple

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I have this sentence where I am not sure about two things:

1. "after launch" – is that correct when I talk about a device?
2. "since then" – is that correct with the past simple tense?

I'm sorry for the lack of the context. The values are provided to an upstream system, hence I used "provided". It is a device for measuring of the water pH - so I thought a device can be "launched". When you start it, it provides the upstream system with the first (or initial) value in 100-200 ms. After that, it continuously provides updates.

> The first value is obtained 100-200 ms **after launch** and is continuously provided in the defined interval **since then.**

Comment: The example sentence is totally ungrammatical/non-idiomatic in so many ways I think this is really just proofreading by another name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: what are the issues then? What is the purpose of this site if mistakes are not corrected and questions downvoted instead? ...

Comment: @user970696: There are several "issues" (apart from the simple *fist/first* typo). ELL is not a proofreading service, and the OP has given so little context that I'm inclined to think even the use of words like **launch** and **provided** here is probably inappropriate. My point is the "sentence" is so bad it would be grossly misleading to simply replace the (definitely) inappropriate **since then** with something like **thereafter**. Just doing that wouldn't salvage the text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Would that be better? "The initial value is obtained in 100-200 ms after the start and is continuously updated in defined interval thereafter.

Comment: @user970696: The first **in** there should be deleted. There's probably no elegant way to include a short **and** clause in exactly this context for the exact meaning I assume (now, after an edit) OP wants to convey. The mopst natural/common phrasing would probably be *...and is continuously updated **at defined intervals** thereafter*, but that kinda fudges the issue as to whether it's *always the same "defined interval" thereafter*. Logically, it's almost bound to be the same, but one could speculate the instrument might thereafter update at, say, constantly doubling intervals.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks. Instead of that "in", should "within" be used as CocoPop suggested? For me it is still hard to understand that it means "from 100 to 200". I always thought "within" is bound with "from now..till"

Comment: @user970696: That first preposition (or lack of one) is a rather uncertain area even in more "normal" contexts where we might say something like *"The rocket will lift off within 10 seconds of ignition"* (which would be true if lift-off occurred immediately, or only ***one*** second after ignition). OP's example is more akin to *"The rocket will lift off **between 7 and 10 seconds after** ignition"*. It's all awkward, because there are so many fine details trying to be crammed into one short sentence. Essentially, it's extremely dense "technobabble/specifications", not "conversational English"

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a technical term I don't know about, **launch** is used for the moment when a product goes on the market and is effectively **launched** by the manufacturer. Otherwise spacecraft are **launched** into space. Hard to tell without knowing what kind of device.

**since then** in that sentence is awkward as hell, if not downright incorrect.

I would use **thereafter** or **from thereon in** or **from that point forward** (in order of personal preference).

Comment: Hmm, computer games often have that button in the installer -- "Launch".. As for the "since then"..does not sound incorrect to me but I am not a native speaker :)

Comment: (1) Thank you, that may be the "technical term" I was talking about; (2) Bingo!

Comment: I would rather use "after the start" - IMHO that is clear enough. What other problems are there with the sentence as FumbleFingers mentioned in his comments to the OP's question?

Comment: "After the start" is almost as bad as "since then." The sentence is dismal - I only addressed "after the launch" and "since then" because that's what the OP questioned specifically.

Comment: I meant to replace "after the launch" with "after the start". I am really interested what is so bad about this sentence, could you rewrite it as you would say it?

Comment: "The first value is obtained within 100-200 ms of the launch, and is updated at regular intervals from that point forward." to give one possibility.

Comment: The point is - from the description - it is not within 100-200 ms but it is in at least 100, at most 200 ms.

Comment: that's what within means...

Comment: right, now I get it. Because within 100 ms means from 0-100 but when you say within 100-200, you declare the range! Am I right? So it cannot be less than 100

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: No, it can't be less than 100; the range is 100 to 200 with "within"